# How is it possible to search on google without https?

Tags: https, keyword, google-search

How to get the searched keywords of the query? I could not find a way. Even on a private-tab www.google.com is redirected to https://www.google.com .

But `wget http://www.google.com` does not redirect to https.
Should it be possible on an old browser or a non graphical browser?

Comment: [Doesn't look like there's a non-HTTPS way](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2296351/Goodbye-Keyword-Data-Google-Moves-Entirely-to-Secure-Search). Also seemingly not a programming question, probably be better suited on [su] or [webapps.se] or somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I found this: Try visiting http://www.google.com/?nord=1 if you don't want to be redirected to HTTPS version